# All VMs PowerCLI Info output /Console and Custom Object Not Working Properly

Tags: powershell, powercli

I want to to get all our VMs with the vSphere PowerCLI and get those outputed with some additional info. But i don't get the output working properly.

I tried it as Console output already but then i dont get the name with the os and IPAddress

```
$Object = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    Name = $name
    OS = $info.OSFullName
    IP = $info.IPAddress
    }

Connect-VIServer -Server VMServer -Credential admin -Password ASecretPWnoOneKnows

$allnames = Get-VM

foreach($name in $allnames)
{
    $info = Get-VMGuest $name | select OSFullName, IPAddress
    Add-Member -InputObject $Object
}
```

This is my "best approach" so far.

My result should look like

```
SomeVMname SomeOS SomeIP
```

but I only got so far the `Length` of the total String or error as I don't handle the custom object properly:

Therefore if someone can help me either way, Console output or into a object which i can also export to csv I would be really happy with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close to making this work already. You just need to move the `$object` creation and retrieval inside of your `ForEach` loop.

```
Connect-VIServer -Server VMServer -Credential admin -Password ASecretPWnoOneKnows
$allnames = Get-VM

$Output = foreach($name in $allnames)
{
  $Object = [PSCustomObject][ordered]@{
    Name=$name.Name
    OS=$name.Guest.OSFullName
    IP=$name.Guest.IPAddress -match "\." -join " "
  }
  $Object
}
$Output # To output to the console
$Output | Export-Csv -path "file.csv" -NoTypeInformaton # Csv output
```

[AVShalom's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55357260/11025476) alludes to some of the ideas regarding handling the `IPAddress` property and the removal of unnecessary commands, i.e. `Get-VMGuest`, to reach the desired goal. He uses a shortcut method for creating the object `$row` that will hold the virtual machine properties. However, there are inherent inefficiencies with using array replacement plus addition technique `$Report += Row` because a new array object of larger size is created each time the loop iterates. For smaller data sets, this may not matter, but for larger ones, this could prove significant.

Once the `[PSCustomObject]` is created, you can edit the value in the properties as long as that object is not destroyed and/or those property definitions remain on the object. This means you can have all new values (if you wish) for the **same properties** during each iteration of the loop. I added the `[ordered]` attribute so that the `$object` property order would remain consistent in your output.

I added the `$Output` variable to store the value of `$Object` during each iteration of the loop. `$Output` becomes an array of objects with the three properties you want to track. Now your `Export-Csv` will convert those property values into strings for your CSV file.

I removed the `Get-VMGuest` command because the `$name` variable is an object that contains all the information you already need. The `Guest` property provides the information that `Get-VMGuest` provides.

You could cast the `IPAddress` value to string because there could be times where there is more than one IP since that property is an array. You can choose to grab just an indexed value (`$Name.Guest.IPAddress[0]`); however, you must be careful with this because the IP address(es) you want, may be at another index. The `[string]` cast will return all values of that property using a space delimiter. I used the `-join` operator instead and used a space delimiter. `IPAddress` may also contain IPv6 addresses. I only wanted to capture IPv4 addresses, so I used a Regex match, e.g. `$Name.Guest.IPAddress -match "\."`, which matches the literal `.` character. You can combine multiple techniques to get the data you want.

**Consider the following object and examples:**

```
$name.guest

IPAddress                                     OSFullName
---------                                     ----------
{1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.2, fe80::ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff} Windows StackOverflow

$name.guest.IPAddress # Retrieves all IPs
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2
fe80::ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff

$name.guest.IPAddress[0] # Retrieves the first IP in the array
1.1.1.1

$name.guest.IPAddress -match "\." # Retrieves all IPv4 IPs
1.1.1.1
2.2.2.2

$name.guest.IPAddress -match "\." -join " " # Retrieves all IPv4 separated by space
1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2
```

With the way your code was structured, it appeared as though you were trying to create properties whose values are by reference rather than by value. To explain further, it appears that you want the property values for `$Object` to update as the `$info` property values change **automatically** without an explicit assignment. I do not know if that was your intention, but I believe that would add complexity to what you want to accomplish. I did not do this for your code. I am setting the `$Object` property values explicitly each time the loop iterates.

I also did not see your `Export-Csv` command; however, you described having an output of the `Length` property. That can happen when you `Export-Csv` with a `[string]` object as the input object. Since the purpose of `Export-Csv` is to convert property values into strings, the only property value of a regular string is `Length`. So that is to be expected. You can see this behavior below:

```
$str = "this is a string"
($str | Get-Member).where({$_.MemberType -eq "Property"})


   TypeName: System.String

Name   MemberType Definition
----   ---------- ----------
Length Property   int Length {get;}
$str | ConvertTo-Csv
#TYPE System.String
"Length"
"16"
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear and informative answer, but as you mentiond "trying to create properties whose values are by reference rather than by value" -> what does that actually mean. I'm still pretty new to Powershell and all learning by myself and this forum but i dont even have a clue what this means

Comment: I added explanation to that section. Hope that helps. I can remove that section entirely if you think it is not helpful for the scenario. I am going to update the IP address section further since you could be dealing with IPv4 and IPv6 data.

Comment: I think i have a clue what this means, and that was definitly not what i intended to do. Thank you for your further explaination. And yep i'm dealing with IPv4 and IPv6 and was looking myself for a solution but i appricated every kind of help and information

Comment: as i tested the code i only got back 1 VM but this one VM for about 50times what could make this error occure. IT is the last one only

Comment: I updated the original code to only store IPv4 addresses inside of `$object`.

Comment: i got one more question about the ouput, as console output the IP Address works properly (displayed as array if i'm not worng) but as it goes to the CSV export it exports only _System.Object[]_

Comment: @Kevin, are you running my latest code? I have made a few changes to account for IPv4 IP arrays.

Comment: yes i did but it seems to behave in diffrent ways if you run it as single command or in the foreach loop, because when i'm running it as a single command its perfetcly fine and in the foreach loop it seems to to be an array kinda confuses me EDIT/Update: i did forget the  `-join " "` param

Comment: everything is fine, @AdminOfThings +1

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `Get-VMGuest` to get OS/IP information, you already have it with `Get-VM` using the `Guest` property member:

Should be as simple as that:

```
Connect-VIServer -Server VMServer -Credential admin -Password ASecretPWnoOneKnows

$Report = @()
$VMs = Get-VM
foreach ($vm in $VMs)
{
$row = "" | Select Name,OSFullName,IP
$row.Name = $vm.name
$row.OSFullName = $vm.Guest.OSFullName
$row.IP = $vm.Guest.IPAddress[0]
$Report += $row
}
```

- Note that the IPAddress may include more then one IP, e.g. IPV4/V6, in the example I collect the first one `[0]` You can use regex to match specific pattern

Comment: is there a short answer for how i could regex this, i did once a few regex puzzle's but never did use it in any code